# How to implement a "delete all" button in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have an index page of elements, and I'm trying to implement a "Delete" button that will send a delete request to the controller with a list of the elements user has checked. So far I've done the following

```
#routes.rb
resources :messages, :except=>[:update,:edit] do
  member do
   delete :delete_all
  end
end      

#index.html.haml
=button_to "Delete", {:controller=>"messages", :action => "delete_all"}, :method=>"delete"
...
=check_box "message", "mark"

#messages_controller.rb
def delete_all
  ....
end
```

I've been trying to do it RESTfully, but I've come across routing errors and other tricky problems. Like, for instance, when I used pure AJAX I come across the problem with the before_filter that wants to authenticate the user, and it doesn't let my request through.

Can anyone explain to me what I need to do? How do I implement this button?

Comment: Could you explain how that situation isn't working for you now?

Comment: Sorry. The code above throws "No route matches {:controller=>"messages", :action=>"delete_all"}"

Comment: Try using `collection do` for the route, since this is how you use it in your view (without an `:id`).

Comment: @wukerplank: That worked. Thank you. I have another question, but I'll ask it as another post. (If you submit this as an answer I can accept it as correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `collection do` for the route, since this is how you use it in your view (without an `:id`).